# How can I run a Cloud ML preprocessing on the cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

Pre-processing can be done locally and on the cloud. I know how to run it locally.

How do I run it on the cloud?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Datalab, simply type %ml preprocess --cloud into a cell, and the generated template will have cloud hooks.

If you want to change existing code, then replace DirectPipelineRunner by DataflowPipelineRunner.  You will also need to specify a few “command-line” arguments.

Here’s an example:

```
RUNNER = 'DataflowPipelineRunner'
OUTPUT_DIR = 'gs://{0}/preprocessed_output/'.format(BUCKET)
options = {
    'staging_location': os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, 'tmp', 'staging')
    'temp_location': os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, 'tmp'),
    'job_name': 'preprocess' + '-' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y%m%d-%H%M%S'),
    'project': PROJECT,
    'extra_packages': [ml.sdk_location],
    'teardown_policy': 'TEARDOWN_ALWAYS',
    'no_save_main_session': True
}
opts = beam.pipeline.PipelineOptions(flags=[], **options)
pipeline = beam.Pipeline(RUNNER, options=opts)
```